# Get method is being called infinitely

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am fetching the data to populate it on the form but when I try to edit the data in the input, the input value will return to its original value and it is because of the get method that is infinitely render on the component. I really need your eyes to see something that have missed or missed up. Thanks in advance y'all.

*fetch method*

```
import * as api from '../api/profile';

export const getProfile = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.fetchProfile();
        
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ALL', payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

*Profile container*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect }  from 'react';

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getProfile } from '../../../actions/profile'; //fetch method
import Profile from './Profile';

function Index() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);
    const currentId = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getProfile()); 
    }, [currentId, dispatch]);

  return (
        <div className="custom-container">
        {posts.map((profile) => (
            <div key={profile._id}>
                <Profile profile={profile} currentId={currentId} />
            </div>
        
        ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Index;
```

*Profile form component*

```
import './Profile.css';
import { React, useState, useEffect }  from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { TextField  } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { updateProfile } from '../../../actions/profile';

 const Profile = ({ profile, currentId }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    currentId = profile._id;
    const [postData, setPostData] = useState(
        {
            profile: {
                name: "",
                description: "",
                email: "",
                number: "",
            }
                
        }
    );

    const post = useSelector((state) => currentId ? state.posts.find((p) => p._id === currentId) : null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(post) setPostData(post);
    }, [post])

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(currentId) {
            dispatch(updateProfile(currentId, postData));
        }
    }
  
    return (
        <form autoComplete="off" noValidate className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            
            <TextField
            id="name"
            name="name"
            className="name"
            label="Full Name"
            variant="outlined"
            value={postData.profile.name}
            onChange={(e) => setPostData({...postData, profile: {...postData.profile, name: e.target.value}})}
            />

            <TextField
            id="outlined-multiline-static"
            label="Multiline"
            multiline
            rows={4}
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            className="mb-3"
            name="description"
            value={postData.profile.description}
            onChange={(e) => setPostData({...postData, profile: {...postData.profile, description: e.target.value}})}
            fullWidth
            />

            <TextField
            id="email"
            label="Email"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            className="mb-3"
            name="email"
            value={postData.profile.email} 
            onChange={(e) => setPostData({...postData, profile: {...postData.profile, email: e.target.value}})}
            />
            <TextField
            id="phone"
            label="Phone Number"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            name="phone"
            value={postData.profile.number}
            onChange={(e) => setPostData({...postData, profile: {...postData.profile, number: e.target.value}})}
            />
            <Button variant="light" type="submit" className="Save">Save</Button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default Profile;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your getProfile action ?

Comment: The right way to use `useState` should be `const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState(null);`

Comment: @jossefaz I added. Please check.

Comment: @bcjohn Let me try that

Comment: As @bcjohn pointed out : you passed the currentId which is an array as it was a value type... this wont work. Not sure that this is the source of your problem but i'd check that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In useEffect you have passed like this , in Profile Container

```
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getProfile()); 
    }, [currentId, dispatch]);
```

in params you have passed dispatch also , so it will call dispatch every time dispatch runs , so it is called infinite times , remove it

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(post) setPostData(post);
}, [post])
```

The post will be a different object each time. check for post property in useEffect dependency like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(post) setPostData(post);
}, [post.profile.description])
```

Also, why are you changing prop value below in Profile component?

```
currentId = profile._id
```